# Как правильно очистить массив кроме первого[0] значения в цикле?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив.

```
items = []
items[0] = {id: "805", category: 'Apple'}
items[1] = {id: "804", category: 'Plum'}
items[2] = {id: "805", category: 'Watermelon'}
items[3] = {id: "804", category: 'Grape'}

function Test {
    var result = '';
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        result += item.category + '\n';
    });
    console.log(result);
}
<button onclick='Test();'>тест</button>
```

При каждом клике на кнопку вызывается функция, которая выводит в консоль значение `category`. 
Моя проблема заключается в том, что в консоли выводится `APPLE` - при одном клике на кнопку. При втором - `PLUM APPLE`, и если на 3 -

```
WATERMELON PLUM APPLE.
```

Мне же нужно получить вывод при каждом клике только одного значения. То есть при дальнейшем вызове функции - подтягиваются предудыщие значения. Полагаю что нужно очищать массив, но как это сделать в данном случае ?

Comment: "ARGENTINA" - какая Аргентина? откуда Аргентина?

Comment: "GREEN" - какая Грин? откуда Грин?

Comment: @Igor, PLUM ARGENTINA, APPLE GREEN - изначальное название категорий, которые я сократил до PLUM, APPLE. Поправил.

Comment: Вообще говоря, приведенный код при **каждом** клике на кнопку выводит **все** значения `category` из массива, что никак не соответствует описанию проблемы в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вполне можно обойтись без изменений массива при выводе (и без лишних глобальных переменных):

```js
var items = [
  {id: "805", category: 'Apple'}, 
  {id: "804", category: 'Plum'}, 
  {id: "805", category: 'Watermelon'}, 
  {id: "804", category: 'Grape'}
]; 
var generator = categoryGenerator(items); 

function* categoryGenerator(itemsArr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; i++)
    yield itemsArr[i].category; 
}

function test() {
  let n = generator.next(); 
  if(n.done === false)
    console.log(n.value);
}
```

```html
<button onclick='test();'>тест</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

То, что Вы описываете, не может происходить в Вашем коде, если массив `items` не меняется между нажатиями на кнопку.

Непонятно, какой смысл Вы вкладываете в фразу: "подтягиваются предудыщие значения".

```js
var items = [
  {id: "805", category: 'Apple'},
  {id: "804", category: 'Plum'},
  {id: "805", category: 'Watermelon'},
  {id: "804", category: 'Grape'}
];

var index = 0;
function Test() {
  var result;
  if (index < items.length) {
    result = items[index++].category;
  } else {
    result = "Index is out of range - " + index;
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<button onclick='Test();'>тест</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

если ссылка на массив одна то items  = items[0]; иначе items.length = 1;